# Excel column locking

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do you lock individual columns in Excel? I can lock an entire row but not individual columns. There must be a way to lock individual rows, but I cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

[This article from office.microsoft.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/freeze-or-lock-rows-and-columns-HP010342542.aspx) was literally the second link in Google for the search `excel lock column`.  ... and there's more than one way to do it, too, so check the link for instructions.  Applies to Excel 2010, so if you have a different version and can't figure it out, you might want to specify which version you're actually using.

Comment: Thank you! I actually needed to freeze or lock rows and columns and I used used this article:http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/cells/protect2011.php

Comment: At the moment, this post is essentially only a link. To make sure the answer remains useful even if the link breaks, please edit it to include the relevant information. (Your answer was discovered in [an effort to repair or remove old link-only answers](http://meta.superuser.com/q/11113/380318).)

Comment: @BenN Well, feel free to edit in the appropriate info from that link into this answer.  Or blow away this answer.  Or blow away the whole Q&A.  A  microsoft.com link is pretty safe, and I've put forward as much effort as I'm willing to on answering this lazy question.